# django , list of models to list of string

Tags: python, django, list, django-models

I have a list of model objects:

just an example (I'm not really doing a list of all()):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    #Some other fields....

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

mylist = list(Tag.objects.all())
```

What's the best way of converting this to a list of strings ?
Do I have to iterate the list ?

I was doing something like:

```
newList = [ t.str() for t in mylist ]
```

Any better way ?

Comment: I think that if you really need a list of strings your code is fine. The question is, do you really need to convert to string? Remember that the templates user your `__str__` or `__unicode__` method so you do not need to pass them strings. You could also do [x.name for x in mylist], that may be a little faster.

Comment: It's not for a template... I'm getting a list of items with a complex query. then i need to get one of the fields as string and pass that list to another query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
newList = [ str(t) for t in mylist ]
```

or

```
newList = map( str, myList )
```

But generally, we don't bother.  We just leave it to the template to convert the query set into strings when the template is rendered.

Comment: How do you render it in the template ?

Comment: The usual way: `{% for item in the list %}{{item}}{% endfor %}`  The items are automatically converted to strings in the template.  You should see this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/